# Apache Kafka 2.0 get the consumer lag

Tags: apache-kafka

I use `Kafka 2.0.0 (Commit:3402a8361b734732)`

and would like to check the Kafka consumer lag on the topic for the particular group

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --topic imdb.title --zookeeper localhost:2181 --group decisionwanted
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker
```

How to properly get the lag value on this Kafka version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class has apparently been removed in 1.0. Use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to get consumer group details.

Comment: Thanks ! the following command works like I need `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group decisionwanted`